# Error in a collation for german characters

Tags: linux, mysql, utf-8

I would like to use the collation `utf8_german2_ci` in my linux server. The problem is that I want to use this character `ß` which is not supported in other collation I think. So I get this error `ERROR 1273 (HY000): Unknown collation: utf8_german2_ci`, which is normal since when I use

> show collation like 'utf8%'

there isn't this one collation.

Do u know how I could download it or use it?

Thanks in advance!

Dimitra

Comment: Which software are you referring to?

Comment: it is a linux server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The utf8_german2_ci collation is only available in [MySQL 5.6 or higher](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=38758). Previous versions of MySQL do not contain it.

Comment: I tried to upgrade it but it seems that I can't. Is there a way to use it somehow else?

Comment: Sorry, no, you will have to use MySQL 5.6 or higher.

Comment: Do you know if there is a tutorial that I could use to install MySQL 5.6 in my linux debian server?